# create df column name by adding global variable name and a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a global variable 

`split_ask_min = 'Minimum_Spend'`

I would like to create a new variable in my df and name it 'Minimum_Spend_Sum' and make it the sum of Minimum_Spend.

`var_programs['split_ask_min+ _Sum'] = var_programs[split_ask_min].groupby(X['NAME']).transform('sum')`

I am having trouble creating the variable name. It should be

`split_ask_min+ '_Sum'`
 
which equal to 

`Minimum_Spend_Sum`

But then if I code

`var_programs['split_ask_min+ '_Sum'']`

I got an error

Comment: your question is unclear, are you after `df['split_ask_min_Sum'] = Minimum_Spend_Sum`

Comment: No. I am having trouble creating the variable name. Let me edit my question to make it more clearer.

Comment: So are you after the reverse: `Minimum_Spend_Sum = df['split_ask_min_Sum']`? Can you post raw data, code and the desired output as your question is really unclear

Comment: OK I think you're after `df[split_ask_min + '_Sum'] = some_var`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you really need to create a variable, use a dictionary to store the value.

```
df = {}
split_ask_min = 'Minimum_Spend'
df[split_ask_min + '_Sum'] = ...
print(df)
```

Otherwise you can use `globals()`

```
globals[split_ask_min + '_Sum'] = ...

# Minimum_Spend_Sum => ...
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a new column in your df you can pass a constructed string to add a new column to your df:

```
In [239]:
split_ask_min = 'Minimum_Spend'
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))
df[split_ask_min + '_Sum'] = 0
df

Out[239]:
          a         b         c  Minimum_Spend_Sum
0 -0.113483 -0.487551  0.276176                  0
1  0.143454 -1.322578 -2.040297                  0
2 -0.100320  0.716255  1.109432                  0
3 -1.260516 -0.560957  0.007871                  0
4  0.497407 -2.031782  0.933199                  0
```